# GoogleNews CSS style

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, google-style-guide

I want to create a news aggregator with an interface similar to GoogleNews. Very little experience with HTML/CSS, couldn't do it just with inspect. Is there any way to include (or download) the stylesheet, so I can create an interface similar to Google. I found something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
```

But still couldn't get it, even the navigation bar with the search input text in it. I have done all the work on the background, but stucked in the front end, do not know where is the best start point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google News has a great deal of its CSS inlined, so you won't find an easy plug-and-play stylesheet like you're describing. I suggest you create a simple three-column layout using Bootstrap or Foundation. You'd save time by not having to remove and/or make sense of all of Google's proprietary markup and CSS and you'd have a better grasp of what's going on.